# Ajax call won't pass - form always submitted by php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I've a form which is submitting with php uri_request by default.
Now i was trying to add an ajax call to submit the form, but it's still submitting with php 
The ajax call for submitting the form is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#contactform").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        type: 'POST',
        data: ("#contactform").serialize(),
        url: 'formfiles/submit.php',
        // for ajax the submit.php is on a             
        success: function() {
            // separate page 
            $('#contactform').fadeOut(200).submit();
            $('#success').delay(200).fadeIn(200);
        }
    });
    return false;

});
```

and the html form attributes are:

```
<form action="#n" class="active" method="post" name="contactform" id="contactform">
```

Also the

```
 e.preventDefault
```

at the beginning of the ajax call won't work, but without the ajax it work (only the prevent default!)

What is wrong with the code? Why it doesn't work?

Thanks in advance for any help

**EDIT**  here is the html {in an include file ( the hole site is a php dynamic structure)}

```
<form action="#n" class="active" method="post" name="contactform" id="contactform">

<div class="column">
    <div class="obb" style="<?php echo $color[11];?>">
                    All fields are mandatory
                    </div>
      <div >
<label style="<?php echo $color[0]; ?>"> Name:</label>
    <input class="con_campo required" name="name" value="" id="name" type="text" />

        </div>
        <div >
          <label style=""><?php echo $color[8]; ?>&nbsp;</label>                                                    

  </div>
<div class="fieldcontent prod" id="pr">
                   <label style="">&nbsp;<?php echo $color[2]; ?></label>
<select name="prod" value="" id="products" class="selectx required">
  <option  value=""> -- Select -- </option>
  <option value="1"> ITA</option>
 <option value="2">DE</option>
 <option value="3"> FR</option>
 <option value="4">EN</option>

  </select>

                </div>
            <div class="fieldcontent prod" id="in">
                <label style="<?php echo $color[4]; ?>"> Address:</label>
<input name="address" value="" id="address" class="required" type="text"     />

                        </div>
                         <div class="fieldcontent prod" id="ci">
                        <label style="<?php echo $color[6]; ?>"> City:</label>
   <input name="city" value="" id="city" class="con_campo required" type="text" />

                       </div>
                        <div class="fieldcontent info help" id="me" >
                          <label style="<?php echo $color[10]; ?>">Message:</label>
<textarea id="message" name="message" value="" class="cs_comment required" ></textarea>

                        </div>
                        <div id="code" style="margin-bottom:25px;">
     <label style="<?php echo $color[11]; ?>; width:340px;"></label> 
<input type="text" name="code" class="chapta" size="10" maxlength="7" id="code"/>

                        </div>
            </div>
<div class="column" >
                 <div class="obb">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="fieldcontent prod" id="co">
    <label style="<?php echo $color[1]; ?>">Surname:</label>
<input name="surname" value="" id="surname" class=" required" type="text"/>

            </div>
            <div >
<label style="<?php echo $color[9]; ?>">Email: </label>
<input name="email" value="" id="email" class=" required email" type="text" />

</div>
 <div class="fieldcontent help prod" id="do">
<label style="<?php echo $color[3]; ?>">Domain:</label>
            <span style="font-size:20px; margin-left:30px;"> http://</span>
<input name="domain"  id="domain" class=" required" type="text" value="" />

            </div>
                        <div class="fieldcontent prod" id="re">
    <label style="<?php echo $color[5]; ?>">Region:</label>
   <input name="region" value="" id="region" class=" required" type="text" />

                        </div>
               <div class="fieldcontent prod" id="pa">
<label style="<?php echo $color[7]; ?>" >State:</label>
<input name="state" value="" id="state" class="con_campo required" type="text" />

                        </div>
                    </div>

                  <div>
        <div class="bottom">

<input type="submit" id="submitButton" name="submit" value="submit" />
                        &nbsp;<br /><br /><br />&nbsp;

        </div>
                </form>
 </div></div>

<script> 
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#contactform").submit(function(e){
    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        type: 'POST',
        data: $("#contactform").serialize(),
        url : 'formfiles/submit.php',   // for ajax the submit.php is on a             
        success: function() {            // separate page 
            $('#contactform').fadeOut(200).submit();
            $('#success').delay(200).fadeIn(200);
        }
    }); 
  });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can restructure your code to fix the problem as below. You don't need `return false;` since `e.preventDefault();` is gonna take care of it.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#contactform").submit(function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            type: 'POST',
            data: $("#contactform").serialize(), //note that $ mark is added
            url: 'formfiles/submit.php', // for ajax the submit.php is on a             
            success: function () { // separate page 
                $('#contactform').fadeOut(200).submit();
                $('#success').delay(200).fadeIn(200);
            }
        });

    });


});
```

Comment: I had tried the code, but it won't still work. Also tried another solutions, writing in different ways the ajax call, but the code won't work. Is it important WHERE to put the call? Before or after the form? Also, is it possibile that there is some conflict with other jquery scripts?

Comment: As long as your code is in $(document).ready(function () { it does nt matter where you have put the code in the page. Check the developer tools(FireBug) for JS errors

Comment: it show's nothing on the console. It seems that the ajax call doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in the ajax call in the line `data: ("#contactform").serialize()`. It should be  `data: $("#contactform").serialize()`

Try this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#contactform").submit(function(e){
        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            type: 'POST',
            data: $("#contactform").serialize(),
            url : 'formfiles/submit.php',   // for ajax the submit.php is on a             
            success: function() {            // separate page 
                $('#contactform').fadeOut(200).submit();
                $('#success').delay(200).fadeIn(200);
            },
            error: function(error_response){
               console.log(error_response);
            }
        }); 
    });
});
```

**Update :**

I see some issues with your code.

1. Is the required jQuery library loaded ? I don't see that in the html you had pasted. Hopefully you have included it in the header or so.
2. Add an `e.preventDefault ();` to prevent the form's default action since the input type is `submit`. If you don't put that the form will be submitted by default method.
3. I don't see the `script` tag closed. You should close the `script` tag else it will not work. Please see below the updated code:

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
       $("#contactform").submit(function(e){
           e.preventDefault();
           $.ajax({
               cache: false,
               type: 'POST',
               data: $("#contactform").serialize(),
               url : 'formfiles/submit.php',   // for ajax the submit.php is on a             
               success: function() {            // separate page 
                   $('#contactform').fadeOut(200).submit();
                   $('#success').delay(200).fadeIn(200);
               }
           }); 
       });
      });
   </script>
   ```

**New Update**

Here your ajax call is returning no data. So the server will not know whether the call is success or not, it will always go to the success function. So you have to check whether the response is success or not. From the PHP page return some string like `success` to show whether the validation or form submission and its processing has been success or else return the error. Also on success callback you are submitting form again, so this will continue as a never ending loop.

Please make the below changes :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#contactform").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            type: 'POST',
            data: $("#contactform").serialize(),
            url : 'formfiles/submit.php',   // for ajax the submit.php is on a             
            success: function(response) {            // separate page 
                if (response == 'success') {
                  //write what you want to do on success
                    $('#success').delay(200).fadeIn(200);
                } else {
                  //show error
                }
            }
        }); 
    });
   });
</script>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Still not working!! Why?? Maybe some conflict? possibile? The position WHERE to put the call is important?

Comment: @Someone33 Can you post your complete HTML form

Comment: @Someone33 The code is working and the ajax call is going. What is the response of the ajax. You have write the success function for ajax. please do write the error method. Check my new edit. The error response will print in the browser console. Can you check what is the error

Comment: @Someone33 are you sure the form submit function is called. Can you put some alert inside  $("#contactform").submit(function(e){  to check whether that request is made

Comment: Submit function is called for sure, 'cause the form is submitting always with php. Put also an `alert("working.");` inside the call. Still not working :-(

Comment: Sure, the library is load. All the necessary files are in the index.php page, but the form is in an include file `index?p= products`. Sorry for the <script> tag, it's an copy/ paste error. All the other jquery is working fine. Maybe the URL path of the ajax call is wrong? But i've included ALL files always from the default `index.php` page

Comment: I don't see any more issues in your code. So you are saying the form submit function is not being rendered. Will it be possible to see this thing? hosted somewhere ??

Comment: I've putted the ajax call in the index page. Now the form will fadeout, but the other jQuery controlls won't work any more. [HERE](http://zengrafic.com/test/zengrafic/index?p=cscart_en) is the path for the site. The form is on the bottom of the site.

Comment: @Someone33 If you check at the page source of the URL you sent you can see you are calling $("#contactform").submit(function(e){} two time. One at the header and one at the footer. Please remove the script of contact form submit and the ajax call at the bottom and then check

Comment: @Someone33 Another issue is that the ajax call is not returning any data and on success call back you are submitting the form. This will execute as a never ending loop. Please check my last edit for updated code

Comment: Updated the page, but `e.preventDefault();` still not working. It's weird.

Comment: Did you update in the website. It still looks same. Please check my last edit on the script

Comment: Ajx call isn't submitting any more. The errors are shown with another jQuery script, so i left the else statement empty. The success id is stored in an php inline-string in the `index?p=cscart_en` file, but this isn't the real problem. Problem is that it doesn't submit any more and i don't know why :-(

Comment: you have to reload the page 'cause of the .htaccess file.

Comment: why is the `e.preventDefault();` now blocking the form?

Comment: The ajax call is actually working. If you check with the network tab in the browser console, you can see the call being sent to submit.php. But that file seems to return a 404 page not found status. The ajax call is not preventing the form submit. Please check

Comment: @Someone33 any update on this. The ajax call is calling wrong page

Comment: Sorry for not responding, but i didn't received any notification of your last message. Thank you very much for your time and help. Yesterday night (G.M.T) i had solved my problem. Please check my account and see my new question, which has been answered . Thanks again